# Why does Windows set it's first time to Pacific?

Tags: windows-7

So I am setting up and patching some new computers. All have Windows 7 Pro. What I have noticed forever is that the default time zone starts at UTC-08:00 Pacific Time (US&Canada). Why is this the default start point?

It is not by hours difference because the first time is UTC-12:00, or alphabetical because it starts with "international" then Coordinated, then Hawaii, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft headquarters is in Washington state, which uses Pacific Time. This is probably the reason.